# Python Error inesperado: Permiso denegado al importar un módulo

Tags: python, python-import, modulos

Hice un archivo de Python su nombre es `miarchivo.py`, y quiero importarlo como módulo en otro archivo.
Al definir lo siguiente:

```py
import miarchivo
```

Me devuelve error y no logro importar.

Al ejecutar, me sale esto:

> Error inesperado: Permiso denegado.

¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 0):

Si estas en ubuntu corre tu archivo como sudo, o bien parate en la carpeta y dale permiso de lectura para todos los usuarios con este comando:

```
chmod -R 777 ./
```

Si estás en windows probablemente el usuario con el que lo estas corriendo no tenga permisos para leer esa carpeta. Te recomiendo ejecutarlo desde una consola con permisos de administrador.